# Understanding the resulting shapes of these numpy slice operations

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get my data correct for the deep learning models I am creating and I stumbled into something peculiar.

I have the following data:

```
>>> original_data.shape
(220, 145, 145)
>>> all_data = np.transpose(original_data, (1,2,0))
>>> all_data.shape
(145, 145, 220)
```

The shape result there is as I require it.

Now when I try to use numpy 'shortcuts' to use this data I get the following:

```
>>> temp = original_data[:][:][0]
>>> temp.shape
(145, 145)
```

This is already confusing as in my mind the shape should be `(220, 145)`

```
>>> temp = all_data[:][:][0]
>>> temp.shape
(145, 220)
```

But why? It would make more sense for it to be `(145, 145)`. But I accepted it as it is and tried the others as well

```
>>> temp = all_data[:][0][:]
>>> temp.shape
(145, 220)
```

Why is this?

```
>>> temp = all_data[0][:][:]
>>> temp.shape
(145, 220)
```

This is blowing my mind

Anyone understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

> Now when I try to use numpy 'shortcuts'

*You are not using Numpy shortcuts*.

Each `[...]` is a separate operation returning a new array object, so you are slicing three times in each example, twice with `[:]` and once with `[0]`. `array[:]` just creates a new *view* on the whole array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> all_data = np.zeros((145, 145, 220))
>>> all_data.shape
(145, 145, 220)
>>> all_data[:].shape
(145, 145, 220)
>>> np.array_equal(all_data[:], all_data)  # the slice is equal to the original
True
```

Adding another `[:]` then just creates another view, and in the end the only operation that actually produces a different result is the `[0]` indexing operation, which then creates a view on *just* the first element of 3-dimensional `(145, 145, 220)` array, (so a 2 dimensional matrix):

```
>>> all_data[:][:].shape
(145, 145, 220)
>>> np.array_equal(all_data[:][:][0], all_data[0])
True
```

You **may as well not have used `[:]` slicing at all**.

You need to pass in your dimension slices as a tuple to a *single* `[...]` indexing operation:

```
>>> all_data[0, :, :].shape  # the same result as all_data[0]
(145, 220)
>>> all_data[:, 0, :].shape
(145, 220)
>>> all_data[:, :, 0].shape
(145, 145)
```

Now you are given a view on the two-dimensional matrix at the specific index.

Comment: It may be worth clarifying what is meant by 'copy' here as slicing in NumPy can be subtly different to regular Python. Specifically, the syntax `array[:]` creates a new ndarray object which has a *view* onto the same underlying data as `array` does. No data in the array is actually being copied in memory here unlike, say, if `array` was a normal Python list (where this syntax would create a shallow copy).